# Publishing an action without using backend server

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using this code for my facebook request, which posts an image as well as text to the user's feed:

My question is, how can I add a parameter for location? I followed this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/show-nearby-places/

But I am unable to use a backend server. In the case that I don't want to use a backend server, how can I modify my code to publish a story, including the location (preferably linking to the facebook location) without using a backend server? I have the user selecting the place, and that works flawlessly. Currently I am interested in getting the  "at Patxi's Chicago Pizza" to appear without using a backend server. Is this possible?

[image]

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:self.textViewForComments.text forKey:@"message"];

//DLog(@"%@",[params objectForKey:@"message"]);

if(self.capturedImageAtFullResolution){

    DLog(@"not null");

    [params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.capturedImageAtFullResolution) forKey:@"picture"];

    /*
    if(canPostSmileysImage){ //##

        //[params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation([self takeScreenShot]) forKey:@"picture"];

    } else {

    }
    */


    [self performPublishAction:^{


        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                     parameters:params
                                     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 //showing an alert for failure
                 DLog(@"%@",error);

                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                 message:@"unable to post"
                                                                delegate:nil
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alert show];

             }
             else
             {
                 //showing an alert for success
                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Posted!"
                                                                 message:@""
                                                                delegate:nil
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alert show];
             }


         }];

    }];



}
```

Comment: in the end I decided to use a back end server because I found no answer to this question.